# Why does Visual Studio replaces my slash with a backslash?

Tags: c#, xml, backslash, visual-studio-2015, slash

In my project I save xml-files to a folder. The variable "header" contains the name of the file.

```cs
string header = "anyString";
```

The line to save the file is:

```cs
xmlDoc.Save($@"D:\00_Coding\00_Repos\MarcSchaetz\MarcSchaetz.STCut\Data\{header}.cutml");
```

That works good and all, except when the header contains a slash (/) like:

```cs
string header = "d/d";
```

Then I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` because Visual Studio couldn't find the path

`"D:\00_Coding\00_Repos\MarcSchaetz\MarcSchaetz.STCut\Data\d\d.cutml"`

So Visual Studio replaces the slash automatically with a backslash. But why and how can I still save a file with a slash in my variable?

Comment: `/` is not a valid file name char. `header` should not contain slash.

Comment: A file-name or directory-name can´t contain a slash as it is used as seperator by the OS.

Comment: I highly doubt Visual Studio is doing that. Did you mean c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does not replace the `/` with `\`. Check this:

```
string header = "d/d";
string result = $@"D:\00_Coding\00_Repos\MarcSchaetz\MarcSchaetz.STCut\Data\{header}.cutml";

//Result: D:\\00_Coding\\00_Repos\\MarcSchaetz\\MarcSchaetz.STCut\\Data\\d/d.cutml
```

As for the use of a `/` in a path - It can't be used for names of files/directories in the operating system. If you try to create on you will get this: (*I tried to insert a `/`*)

[image]

So it just makes sense that the code with throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException` because there really is no directory with that path